# html: Portray data in adjustable columns

Tags: html

I have a list of unknown length (sometimes short sometimes long) that I want to portray on my site. When the list is long it leaves lots of white space if I use 
 after each item. Also just separating the items with spaces looks awkward (crowded).

How do you put them into a list that spills over into more columns if it is a certain length?

Thanks

Comment: can you say something else? its a <table> ? are you using th ? when you talk about length are you referring to width?

Comment: I want a list of items each in their own row, but if the list gets too long I want it to spill over into another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 columns are meant to do this, but they aren't widely supported yet. You can try

```
#container {
    -moz-columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -ms-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
}
```

I believe [Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is also meant to be able to do this as well (I've never used it myself, but I thought that was something it accomplished). The [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) plugin for jQuery looks like another.